# Consolidating overlapping and fragmented line into a single line geometry

Tags: qgis, line, geometry

I have a circular hiking trail. It was digitized in a way that I cannot reproduce. It is apparently a circular path, but it consists of many individual parts that overlap completely or partially. Also, all parts have different directions. In total, I have 1000 such paths, and I want to modify them as automatically and reliably as possible so that only one line geometry remains. I have attached a sample file. If you style the line with transparency, you can see the overlaps.

[image]

This line to download: https://e.pcloud.link/publink/show?code=XZTvkSZtRy14c1VSXfobx4MoMV2CyRk6aay

Comment: If I understand correctly, for your dataset, how about using the tools: 1) build polygons "nativepolygonize"; 2) Convert polygons to lines?

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty, but efficient:

1. [Buffer](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisbuffer)/dissolve lines with a very small distance (like 1 m) and set End cap Style to `Square`
2. Get the [Boundary](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisboundary) of the buffer
3. Run [Multipart to single parts](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)
4. Delete the inner line

Variant:

Instead of step 4, get the center line of the two boundaries of the buffer, using this expression with [Geometry by Expression](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/expression.html):

```
case
when $id = 1
then
    close_line( 
        make_line (
            array_foreach (
                generate_series (1, num_points( $geometry)),
                    with_variable(
                    'vertex',
                    point_n (nodes_to_points ($geometry), @element),
                    centroid (
                        make_line (
                            @vertex,
                            closest_point (
                                geometry ( get_feature_by_id ('Single parts', 2)),  -- Replace Single parts by the name of your layer from step 3
                                @vertex
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
end
```

*Initial red line with overlaps, blue result without overlaps:*

[image]

*Zooming close, you see that the initial red lines had double lines; the blue result just has one line; see measurement tool for distances:*
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use network tools to use the already existing lines for the result, but get rid of parallel, almost but not exactly same lines:

1. Create a few (like 4) more or less evenly distributed points on your line (see screenshot).
2. Run [Shortest Path (layer to point)](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisshortestpathlayertopoint) in [Batch mode](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html?highlight=batch). Fill in the End points automatically by expanding Autofill > Add Values by Expression... with this expression (replace 4 with the number of points created in step 1):

   ```
    array_foreach (
        generate_series (1,4),
        geometry (get_feature_by_id ('points', @element))
    )
   ```

   Then set the other values/use Autofill to automatically copy the values to all rows.
3. Explode/Delete duplicate geometries on the resulting layers, then use [merge vector layers](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgismergevectorlayers) to combine them to one layer.

You might have to create a multipart layer to be able to merge all features to one single feature.

[image]